# Eclipse Preference Synchronizer - changing password

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon, oomph

I'm using **Eclipse Preference Synchronizer** to synchronize the settings on the new Eclipse installation. Unfortunately I have entered an incorrect password and now I'm unable to synchronize nor change the password to the correct one. I can see in the *Error Log* view that the password is incorrect

```
org.eclipse.userstorage.util.ProtocolException: POST    https://api.eclipse.org/api/user/login HTTP/1.1 403 : The username  has not been activated or is blocked.
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.Session$RequestTemplate.getStatusCode(Session.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.Session$RequestTemplate.authenticate(Session.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.Session$RequestTemplate.send(Session.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.Session.retrieveBlob(Session.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.StorageService.retrieveBlob(StorageService.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.Storage.retrieveBlob(Storage.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.userstorage.internal.Blob.getContents(Blob.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.RemoteDataProvider.retrieve(RemoteDataProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.Snapshot.createWorkingCopy(Snapshot.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.Synchronization.createWorkingCopy(Synchronization.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.Synchronization.<init>(Synchronization.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.Synchronizer.createSynchronization(Synchronizer.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.Synchronizer.synchronize(Synchronizer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.sync.SynchronizerJob.run(SynchronizerJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Is there a way to change the password somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already got the [answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1079970&goto=1742043&#msg_1742043) on the Eclipse Community Forum. The credentials for the Eclipse Preference Synchronizer can be changed under `Preferences -> General -> User Storage Service`:

[image: User Storage Service configuration]